# Importing a whole directory of static files in Rollup.js

Tags: javascript, rollup

I am developing a TypeScript library and want to migrate the build process from webpack to rollup.

In my project, I have a directory of SVG icons, sorted into several sub-directories. My library should export a JavaScript object that contains the SVG code of all these icons.

With webpack, I was using [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) to recursively require the SVG files (which were configured as `asset/source`):

```js
const context = require.context("../../assets/icons");
export const icons: Record<string, Record<string, string>> = {};
for (const key of context.keys() as string[]) {
    const [set, fname] = key.split("/").slice(-2);

    if (!icons[set])
        icons[set] = {};

    icons[set][fname.replace(/\.svg$/, "")] = context(key);
}
```

How can I achieve this with rollup?

I have had several ideas so far:

- [rollup-plugin-require-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-require-context) is supposed to bring `require.context` into rollup. However, it seems to be buggy and unmaintained, and in my tests it did not transform the `require.context` call at all.
- [rollup-plugin-glob-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-glob-import) seems to be suitable for recursively importing a directory. I was trying to use it along with [rollup-plugin-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-string) to import the SVG files as plain text. However, it seems like the two plugins don’t communicate with each other, no matter in which order I define them. The glob import plugin complains that my SVG files do not have any exports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1: `rollup-plugin-glob-import`

Using [rollup-plugin-glob-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-glob-import) in combination with [rollup-plugin-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-string) works when configured in the right way.

`rollup-plugin-string` generates modules with a string as its default export, so `format: 'default'` has to be used for `rollup-plugin-glob-import` to import them properly. If sub directory paths should be preserved in the named exports of the resulting bundle, a custom `rename` function can be used (note that the export name needs to be a valid JavaScript variable name, hence the use of `camelCase` here):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'rollup';
import globImport, { camelCase } from 'rollup-plugin-glob-import';
import { string } from 'rollup-plugin-string';

export default defineConfig({
    ...
    plugins: [
        string({
            include: "assets/icons/**/*.svg"
        }) as any,
        globImport({
            format: 'default',
            rename: (name, id) => name || `${camelCase(basename(dirname(id)))}_${camelCase(basename(id, extname(id)))}`
        })
    ]
});
```

`rollup-plugin-glob-import` generates named exports but no default export, so the exported files can be imported like this:

```js
import * as icons from '../../assets/icons/**/*.svg';
```

## Solution 2: Custom plugin

Writing a custom Rollup plugin is not difficult and allows for more flexibility. In particular, it can be used to export a single JSON object rather than one named export per file (whose name is restricted by the allowed characters for JavaScript variable names).

In this example I'm providing a module called `custom:icons`, which has a default export containing all the files:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "rollup";
import glob from 'fast-glob';
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';

export default defineConfig({
    ...
    plugins: [
        {
            name: 'custom:icons',
            resolveId: (id) => {
                if (id === 'custom:icons') {
                    return id;
                }
            },
            load: async (id) => {
                if (id === 'custom:icons') {
                    const icons: Record<string, Record<string, string>> = {};
                    for (const path of await glob('./assets/icons/*/*.svg')) {
                        const [set, fname] = path.split("/").slice(-2);

                        if (!icons[set])
                            icons[set] = {};

                        icons[set][fname.replace(/\.svg$/, "")] = (await readFile(path)).toString();
                    }
                    return `export default ${JSON.stringify(icons, undefined, '\t')}`;
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The custom module can then be imported like this:

```js
import icons from 'custom:icons';
```